# Altitude parameter in Earth view on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

If I go to:

https://www.google.com/maps/@36.9644841,-122.0149787,37m/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en-US

Please note the 37m parameter after the latitude, longitude. Now if I modify it to 20m (I guess it means meters) like this:

https://www.google.com/maps/@36.9644841,-122.0149787,20m/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en-US

now I get an even closer zoom of that location. I guess it's the height from which the user sees that location...

What is the corresponding parameter of this in Google Maps Javascript API?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google earth API's are already deprecated and will continue to work for next few days.

So we are left with Google Maps API only. So I will answer according to that only.

What you are trying to do can be achieved by zoom level in google maps, for example

```
var gMap = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map-canvas'), 
    { zoom : 14 } //Setting default zoom level
);

//To set map to next zoom level
gMap.setZoom(12);
```

Check this for more details
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference

Comment: I know about the zoom but this allows only zooming until 21 for some areas. But if you check my links, with that {nr}m parameter you can zoom closer than 21. This is what I want to achieve, a closer zoom, like that on the official Google Maps website.

Comment: I don't think we can go closer than zoom level 21 while using Javascript API's , there are few things which are not available using API's

I could be wrong but as per what I know its not available in JS API's